# Помогите написать Армянский Алфавит на javascript

Tags: javascript

Помогите написать Армянский Алфавит на javascript через CharCode

Answer (score 6):

Если верить [таблице](https://unicode-table.com/ru/blocks/armenian/), армянские символы идут в диапазоне 0530 — 058F

В десятичном виде: 1328 — 1423

Поэтому в цикле достаточно пройтись по всем этим значениям и вывести их, например так:

```js
var s = '';
for (let i = 1328; i <= 1423; i++)
  s += String.fromCharCode(i) + ' ';

console.log(s);
```